# Localization of $4f$ in rare earth and $3d$ electrons in transition metals

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, atomic-physics, ferromagnetism

Is there a justification for why are the $4f$ electrons strongly localized about the nucleus in rare-earth atoms but the $3d$ electrons in transition metals extend further out from the nucleus? I have hit upon this question while reading about magnetism. Here is a reference from Blundell's Magnetism in Condensed Matter [Sec.4.2.2 second paragraph](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Jk5yDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=if%20the%20electrons%20on%20neighbouring%20magnetic%20atoms%20interact%20via%20an%20exchange%20interaction,%20this%20is%20known%20asdirect%20exchange&source=bl&ots=OoHVgLRO8f&sig=ACfU3U3sqoVu4dKyNkIwUIeFK7q5ZWx4mQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKp8vLmd_iAhWUWisKHdveBroQ6AEwC3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=if%20the%20electrons%20on%20neighbouring%20magnetic%20atoms%20interact%20via%20an%20exchange%20interaction%2C%20this%20is%20known%20asdirect%20exchange&f=false).

A slightly different quote can be found in Kittel's Solid State Physics book which says,

> The difference in the behaviour of the rare earth and the iron group salts is that the $4f$ shell responsible for paramagnetism in the rare earth ions lies deep inside the ions, within the $5s$ and $5p$ shells, whereas the iron group ions in the $3d$ shell responsible for paramagnetism is the outermost shell.

Comment: Well, the 4$f$ electrons are shielded by a closed 5$s$ shell. Look at the electronic configuration of the various elements of interest.

Comment: @JonCuster That's true. But that doesn't work to explain why $3d$ electrons are the outermost.

Answer (score 0):

The crystal field splittings are much larger in transition-metal salts (mostly due to covalency, the ligand-field effect), of the order of electronvolts. In rare-earth salts, crystal field splittings are two orders of magnitude smaller.